# Shorthand for git merge's --no-ff flag

Tags: git, git-merge

Most verbose flags have a shorthand version, for instance

```
git branch --delete
```

has

```
git branch -d
```

Is there a shorthand version of git merge's `--no-ff` flag that I'm missing? I've got an alias setup to shorten the command but I don't get command line tab completion with an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shorthand for `--no-ff`. You can see all the available options in the manual: [git-merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html). If you always use `--no-ff`, you can make it default:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

Comment: That's what I thought, just making sure it wasn't something that I had missed or that was somehow omitted.